# PHP code snippet causes page 404 in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am facing a strange issue with WordPress. When I put this line as a code snippet in a blog post:

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

I get a 404 error when I try to preview the page, and I wont be able to save the post at all but if I make the line of code incorrect for example, remove the last 'e' from require, this way:

```
$app = requir_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

everything works fine. Is the code somehow executing and causing problems?

Comment: `requir_once` is probably being treated as a constant, if wrapped in brackets, does anything change? `$app = require_once(__DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php');`. I would suggest turning on verbose error reporting.

Comment: can you require any other file?

Comment: as long as its valid php, it causes issues

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your web host probably has a paranoid web application firewall (most likely [mod_security](https://modsecurity.org/)) enabled, with rules to block requests which contain data which looks like PHP code.

Contact your web host and request that they turn this feature off.

Comment: I didnt think about this at all, thank you very much

Comment: you were right, resolved the problem this way, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress is a little funny that way, try using get_stylesheet_directory() function. This will return the path to your theme directory.

require_once( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/path/to/bootstrap.css );

Also the require_once function doesn't return anything so there is no point trying to assign it to a variable.

Comment: This code isn't intended to be executed! The OP is trying to make a blog post which contains that text.